# How to continuously deploy a web app when caching is enabled?

Tags: caching, web, deployment, continuous-integration, memcached

In our web app, we have a web page that includes many components, each rendered with data from DB, server side cache is used to  store the generated components for future requests. And we also maintained a global 'last-modified' timestamp for the whole page, which is the last time any data (in database) on this web is changed, and we return 304 HTTP response if the browser cache has a fresh version.

In a word, we use both server side cache and client side cache to improve performance.

This is all good until we consider deploying new code. When new code (say html) is deployed, not only client-side cache is invalid, server side cache has to be purged, too. We have to set the last-modified time to our code deployment time, and purge everything in server side cache.
This is not quite desirable, if we deploy code regularly. Because the data in database for the page is not changed regularly, we expect the caches to work over long period of time. But deploying new code defeats our purpose.

What should we do in this case? Is there any 'industry best practice' here?

Answer (score 0):

For my projects, when I change a file such as a css file, I will add a parameter to where the file is included. For example,

```
<link href='default.css?1' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

And change the number each time you want the file to be reloaded rather than extracted from the cache.

Comment: Yeah, that will work for js and css tags. My concern is mostly about dynamic html and maybe inline js, it is frustrating to see levels of caches invalidated with a small code change.

Comment: Many bundlers uses the hash of the CSS or JS file for this